# How to combine transition and scale animation timelines?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, gsap

I am trying to make a version of [this scroll to scale/translate animation](https://www.portfoliobox.net/jp/) but on steroid, where any panel of the welcome grid can scale/translate to take the full viewport.

I did it with **gsap** but it uses a 2-step animation, one to scale AND THEN one to translate because the translation animation needs the updated position values of the panel that got scaled. And it's not very appealing :
[image: which is not too appealing]

The goal is to have one single animation that both scales and translates **at the same time** the welcome grid so that the target panel can be centered and take the full viewport.

THE PROBLEM

Is there a way to get the updated panel element position as the scale animation is going and seamlessly provide it to a translate method of the same animation ?

Or how would you do it ?

html :

```
<div id="zoomContainer" class="zoomable relative h-full w-full grid grid-cols-5 grid-rows-5 bg-green-300 gap-5">
    <div @click="zoom" class="bg-blue-500"></div>
    <div @click="zoom" class="col-span-2 bg-red-500"></div>
    <div @click="zoom" class="bg-gray-500"></div>

    <div @click="zoom" class="row-span-2 bg-yellow-500"></div>
    <div @click="zoom" class="row-span-2 bg-blue-400"></div>
    <div @click="zoom" class="bg-red-400"></div>
    <div id="p3" @click.stop="zoom" :class="['relative  overflow-hidden bg-image  col-span-2 row-span-2 bg-gray-400', zoomIn ? 'zoomIn' : '']" style="background-image: url(assets/cabine_admin.png)">
        <!-- <img @click="null" src="@/assets/cabine_admin.png" alt="" class="-z-5"/> -->
    </div>
    <div @click="zoom" class="bg-yellow-400"></div>
    <div @click="zoom" class="bg-blue-300"></div>
    <div @click="zoom" class="col-span-2 row-span-2 bg-red-300"></div>
    <div @click="zoom" class="row-span-2 bg-gray-300"></div>
    <div @click="zoom" class="col-span-2 bg-yellow-300"></div>

    <div @click="zoom" class="bg-blue-600"></div>
    <div @click="zoom" class="bg-red-600"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
zoom($event) {
    this.zoomIn = !this.zoomIn;
    var element = $event.target;
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var scaleX = 2;
    var scaleY = 2;
    // get scale ratio for panel element f(viewPort)
    scaleX = window.innerWidth / rect.width;
    scaleY = window.innerHeight / rect.height;

    var tl = gsap.timeline();

    if (this.zoomIn) {
        tl.to(".zoomable", {
            scaleX,
            scaleY,
            ease: 'ease.in',
            duration: 0.3,
            onComplete:  () => {
                // get freshly scaled panel element's bbox
                rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
                tl.to(".zoomable", {
                    translateX: (-rect.left / rect.left) * rect.left + "px",
                    translateY: window.innerHeight - rect.bottom + "px",
                    ease:'ease.out',
                    duration: 0.5,
                });
            },
        });
    } else {
        tl.to(".zoomable", {
            scaleY: 1,
            scaleX: 1,
            translateX: "0%",
            translateY: "0%",
            duration: 0.7,
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minial reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I mean the snippets above are basically all of the code.
I'm using tailwindcss and vuejs
- [This is what i'm trying to achieve (scroll to see the effect)](https://www.portfoliobox.net/jp/) 

* [This is what the code is currently doing (click to see the effect)](https://portfolio.amane.dev/)

Comment: I see your HTML and JS, but I couldn't run it to test and find a solution. Whatever you're using, you should be able to create a minimal example with HTML, CSS and JS so that we could help you out.